# Swift cli application simple http get JSON

Tags: json, swift, api, rest, command-line-interface

I am tryin this simple script/cli in swift to GET json response from this api. But all I get is a blank output.
What am I missing?
This is main.swift:

```
    import Foundation
    
    if let url = URL(string: "https://aws.okex.com/api/swap/v3/instruments/BTC-USD-SWAP/ticker") {
      URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { data, response, error in
      if let data = data {
         if let jsonString = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8) {
            print(jsonString)
         }
       }
   }.resume()
    
    }
```

Comment: thx for the edit

Comment: In a CLI you need at least a run loop.

Comment: @vadian I've seen it done with runloops and I've seen it done with a semaphore. With modern code you can use async/await...

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `JSONSerialization's` `jsonObject(with:)` method to get the *JSON* `Dictionary` from `data`, i.e.

```
if let url = URL(string: "https://aws.okex.com/api/swap/v3/instruments/BTC-USD-SWAP/ticker") {
    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { data, response, error in
        if let data = data {
            if let dict = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data) as? [String:Any] {
                print(dict)
            }
        }
    }.resume()
}
```